# How to render slides from a jupyter notebook after exporting them to html?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, nbconvert

I wrote a jupyter notebook and set up slideshow options to obtain slides and do a presentation. Thus I can see my presentation with

```
jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

Doing this I also obtain a `notebook.slides.html` file. But if I open that file with my browser, the slides are not rendered, I obtain a basic html page. I would like to know how can I render the slides in a browser directly from the html file ?

For example, if you open the `demo.html` file of [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/demo.html) the slides are directly rendered.